# SQL - Select rows with greatest revision that are less than a set revision

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have an audit table where entities are stored by id and an associated revision number and revision type (this is a Hibernate Envers audit table).

E.g.

| id | rev | revtype | foo_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 0 | 10 foo v1 |
| 10 | 3 | 1 | 10 foo v2 |
| 10 | 4 | 1 | 10 foo v3 |
| 20 | 2 | 0 | 20 foo v1 |
| 20 | 4 | 1 | 20 foo v2 |

How can I query this table so that I get the latest revision of each id that is less than a specified revision, e.g. rev=4?

From the example table above, the result of the query for latest revisions less than rev=4 should be:

| id | rev | revtype | foo_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 | 1 | 10 foo v2 |
| 20 | 2 | 0 | 20 foo v1 |

I'm using a MySQL DB, version 5.7.

Comment: which version of mysql are yo using?

Comment: Version 5.7 of MySQL

Comment: In MySQL 5.7 you can: 1) filter the result set with (`rev < 4`); 2) Walk the rows by id and by rev in descending order; 3) Use a variable to produce a row number; 4) Filter the rows according to that row number. Unfortunately I never learned to use variables in MySQL 5.7 so I can't help you with step #3. The rest should be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mysql 8+:

```
select * from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by id order by rev desc) rn
   from tablename
   where rev < 4
) t where rn = 1
```

in mysql 5.7:

```
select * from mytable t1
where (id,rev) = ( 
     select id, rev from mytable t2
     where t2.rev < 4
     and t1.id = t2.id
     order by rev desc limit 1
     )
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c7581fde2a4d5401facb2a3934a03dd)*